# Why is read_csv failing with invalid start byte error?

Tags: python, windows, pandas, csv

**Goal:** To convert .xlsx file to .csv file, then read into pandas dataframe. (**pd.read_excel()** works too).

**Breakdown:**
If I write xlsx file to csv, the csv will error with **pd.read_csv(...**, but if I manually create or change the file it works fine.

```py
import pandas as pd; import csv; import xlrd

# open excel file
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(my_xlsx)
sh = wb.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

# write each row from excel to csv
with open(my_csv, 'w', newline='') as csvFile:
    wr = csv.writer(csvFile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for rownum in range(sh.nrows):
        wr.writerow(sh.row_values(rownum))

# read into dataframe
df = pd.read_csv(my_csv)       # <-- this step throws the byte error
```

This throws the error:

```sh
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x85 in position 17: invalid start byte
```

**Fixes:**
If I alter my_csv file at all after writing by copy all/paste/save, or just edit something and save, there is no longer a byte error.
I haven't found a way to fix the problem without manual intervention.

**Question:**
What is happening here? Does this error have something to do with windows text handling? Is there a way to fix this by forcing UTF-8 encoding in the write step?

I haven't had a chance to test it in Linux, but expect it to work if this is indeed a Windows plain text error. This is a learning point for me more than a hang-up, but help will be appreciated!

A few related questions: [Invalid Start Byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55463532/python-cant-decode-byte-invalid-start-byte), [CSV Windows problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348460/csv-file-written-with-python-has-blank-lines-between-each-row#3348664)

Comment: `open` on windows doesn't default to `utf-8` encoding.  Be explicit about the encoding when open for reading or writing and never be surprised.  Use `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` if you want to know the default used by [open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open).

Comment: Good explanation. My Windows defaults to 'cp1252' encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need to open csv with `encoding='utf-8'` option.

Here is code.

```
import pandas as pd; import csv; import xlrd

# open excel file
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(my_xlsx)
sh = wb.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

# write each row from excel to csv
with open(my_csv, 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as csvFile:
    wr = csv.writer(csvFile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for rownum in range(sh.nrows):
        wr.writerow(sh.row_values(rownum))

# read into dataframe
df = pd.read_csv(my_csv)
```